# Visual Boy Advance Invalid or Not Recognized Save File

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

Today after an annoying problem with my PC I had to format it and reinstall everything.

Of course I made backup of all my files but, as always it seems that I lost something.

I use Visual Boy Advance, specifically a modification of it called VisualLink.  I saved my files regularly using the virtual Flash ROM the emulator provides to save "in game".

But now, after everything is done, all my files have been moved back, I was testing it and the save file is not recognized anymore.  It doesn't show a corrupted message, it simply would not recognize the saved data.

I'm not sure how to fix or workaround this.

The saved data was done after **a lot** of gaming time and I really don't want to have to do it again.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: What is the file format of the files? Are they .sav files? Also, how are you trying to load the files?

Comment: Initially I was using the "normal" version o VBA, which produces *.sav files, but due some requirements along the game I needed to exchange/mix information with another character, played by myself, and then I started using VBALink, which produces *sa1, *sa2... accordingly to the application instance.

Comment: Alright, next question: How are you trying to load the files? Are you using the load command in the menu? Or something else?

Comment: Actually, once these files acts as virtual flash ROM I was loading them through game option. Unfortunally I did not saved the current state as a "Plan C".

Comment: Do you mean [VBALink](http://www.vbalink.info/) instead of VisualLink? Also you may have to set the save paths correctly if you modified the in your previous setup

Answer (score 1):

Check the emulator settings. You most likely have a different save type, you should try to change that and reload the game. If you don't know your old savetype, you'll need to try.

[image]